# Installing 'TruStone' veneer, directly on painted drywall?

Tags: mortar, stone, veneer

I stumbled onto a deal on TruStone SplitFace veneer (looks like stacked stones, glued together), and was hopeful to install them in the front entrance no higher than 5ft high. The surface is just regular drywall, painted in builder's beige!

I couldn't find any info on TruStone's website for recommended install method. These stones are rather heavy, I worry that the paper wouldn't cut it.

I can't find a definitive answer on "modified thinset only" vs. "wire lath w/scratch is enough" vs. the more pedantic "breather type sheathing membrane, plus wire lath plus scratch then using a Type S or Type N mortar" (e.g., http://www.canadianstone.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Natural-Stone-Installation-Guide_10-19-15_web.pdf)

I'm in Canada if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not a good idea. As you said, the stones are heavy. If you could guarantee a solid rest on the floor, maybe, but I'd simply cut out the drywall a few inches inside your stone area, replace it with 1/2" cementboard, and call it good. This would be simpler than the wire lath business. I'd float backing at the joint of the cementboard and drywall to firm things up. Half-inch plywood strips would do well.

Comment: Better then to just replace the drywall with cement board and thinset directly onto it?

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting, but do consult the product literature for an signs that that's not a suitable approach. I'd float backing at the joint of the cementboard and drywall to firm things up. Half-inch plywood strips would do well.